# Globalization of dynamic variables in wso2 Integration Studio

Tags: wso2, global-variables, dynamic-variables, wso2-integration-studio

I've so far been using variables by saving them in a local entry file, and then using $ctx to call them and use them in my proxy. I want to know if there's a way in wso2 Integration studio wherein I can create multiple global variables (eg; to save a host url endpoint or some String values), and call them in my proxy by NOT making use of a local entry file.( Deployment will be using k8 pods)

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to pass environment-specific parameters to the WSO2 pod as environment variables. Once passed as environment variables you can access them as explained [here](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.0.0/micro-integrator/develop/injecting-parameters/).

If you want to assign the value to a `Property` you can do something like the below.

```xml
<property expression="get-property('env','JAVA_HOME')" name="java" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```